# Grant permission on multiple folders using PowerShell

Tags: 2013, powershell, permissions

Can you please help me to grant permission to different folders ?
I used the following article :
[Grant folder permission(SharePoint) using powershell script](http://sharepoint2010tutor.blogspot.com.au/2011/08/grant-folder-permissionsharepoint-using.html)

but when I tried to grant permission for nested folder e.g. I need to grant permission to folder Test11 which is inside folder Test1 it can not do it as the following powershell script:

```
 $doclib=[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPDocumentLibrary]$web.Lists["Shared Documents"]
 $foldercoll=$doclib.Folders;
```

show only the first level of folders

Comment: Could you use the subfolders property of the parent folder?

Comment: You may also want to look into the SPWeb.GetFolder Method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms461547(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thsnks @BlueBird but I found the following error : Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder] does not contain a method named 'BreakRoleInheritance'.

Comment: $doclib.Folders return SPListItemCollection https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.folders.aspx and SPWeb.GetFolder() return SPFolder https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms461547(v=office.15).aspx and I believe that is  the issue /

Comment: I just fix it  its using : $folder.Item.BreakRoleInheritance many thanks @BlueBird for your support

Comment: You should really be more clear about your question, it gives the inclination you are looking how to get subfolders not so much breaking inheritance.